# How to remove indexed URLs from Subdomain without Encountering 404 errors in Google

Tags: wordpress, indexing

I have a domain (ex. test.com) on which wordpress is installed. I also have a another wordpress installed on a subdomain(ex. test.com/blabla). Blabla contains many indexed pages but now I want to remove them completely and delete the wordpress on the blabla subdomain. 
How can I achieve that? Keep in mind that I don't want anything to change in test.com

I would really appreciate your help,
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add attempt you have made to solve your problem.  From there we can help you figure out what to do differently to get this working the way you would like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.htaccess` file can help you to achieve that. Please invest some time to dive into [that](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-).

You have to use the

```
Redirect 301
```

for your subdomain to redirect to the new page or any other page if you want to.

Make sure, that your `robots.txt` allows Google to access the old page directory.
When Google is able to track that the old page has been removed, it will no longer appear as search result.

Then you no longer need to rediect.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still a little fuzzy about this part: "Make sure, that your robots.txt allows Google to access the old page directory." 
I don't undestand as the old page is already indexed.
Can you elaborate that. I'm sorry. I don't have a lot of experience.

Comment: p.s. I don't want to redirect to anything. I want to remove this subdomain completely.

Comment: When the old page is indexed via robots.txt don t worry about that. Some people just try to stop pages from appearing in search results by banning it from the robots.txt - that will not work.

Comment: Google is caching your site. So for now the old subdomain will appear - even if it is not existing. It will take time, that Google again crawles your pages and gets informed, that the subdomain is no longer existing.
For the time it is still in the search results but not existing you should use the redirect that users do not enter any 404.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was very helpful